# How to add value to itemtype in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to add 'itemtype' value to this body tag,

```
body.page-body.ng-scope.device-lg(itemscope='', itemtype='')
```

I tried the following

```
$('body').add(itemtype='t1');
```

But this did not work.

Comment: Please give proper html markup, also preferably in a js fiddle

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask]. Question can be interpreted several ways and therefore is not clear

Answer (score 1):

`itemscope` and `itemtype` are element attributes, set them via `$.attr()` method:

```
$('body').attr('itemscope', 'scope');
$('body').attr('itemtype', 'type');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/